# Wordpress questions

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm usually answering questions in the PHP tag, my wordpress knowledge is about zero, however I see lots of wordpress questions in this tag it's really starting to get annoying. Shouldn't these questions belong on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Some recent examples from when this question was made:

[Wordpress CPT UI Plugin - Comments Feed Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531576/wordpress-cpt-ui-plugin-comments-feed-link)

[Woocommerce API returns 1, but works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531519/woocommerce-api-returns-1-but-works)

[Wordpress - Passing a class method to the query_var hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530650/wordpress-passing-a-class-method-to-the-query-var-hook)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If they're about using or configuring WordPress, then they belong on the WordPress site. If they're about programming, they're on-topic on Stack Overflow.  If you don't want to see WordPress questions you can add the tag to your ignore list.

Comment: This is a great question and good response. The line here seems fuzzy. Some are programming related in the sense of properly using the Wordpress API via code, but at the same time, the question seems less like, hey, I'm having problems with the `php` of this function but with the syntax of the api itself, like why doesn't this filter do what I expect given this code. The question may be a good question, but I would recommend moving it to the Wordpress StackExchange site. Is it just a judgement call at that point whether or not to flag the question?